# SparklyR connection to standalone spark cluster only connecting to 2/6 workers

Tags: apache-spark, rstudio, sparklyr

I've just finally managed to set up my stack to use RStudio to connect to a standalone spark cluster (with file storage in CassandraDB) via sparklyR.

The only issue I still haven't been able to resolve is how to get my sparklyR connection to utilise all the available worker nodes on cluster (there are 6 in total). Every time I connect, the Executor Summary page shows only 2 workers are being utilised by the sparklyR connection (with 1 executor on each node).

I've tried playing around with the config.yml file for the `spark_connect` call, including setting `spark.executor.instances: 6` and `spark.num.executors: 6`, but that doesn't make a difference. Is there another setting I can use to get sparklyR to use all the nodes? Can I somehow pass a list of all the worker IP addresses to `spark_connect` so that it connects to them all?

My setup is as follows: 
RStudio: 1.0.136, 
sparklyR: 0.5.3-9000, 
Spark version (on cluster & locally): 2.0.0.

Comment: Could you share your config.yml file?

Comment: sure, here are the key settings (sorry, not sure how to format this within a comment):

  sparklyr.sanitize.column.names: TRUE
  sparklyr.cores.local: 3
  sparklyr.shell.driver-memory: "8G" 

  spark.executor.memory: "8G" 
  spark.executor.cores: 5 
  spark.cores.max: 12 
  spark.memory.fraction: 0.75 
  spark.memory.storageFraction: 0.5 
  spark.serializer: org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer

Comment: I've also tried adding  `spark.executor.instances: 6, spark.num.executors: 6`, but it makes no difference.

Comment: Could you try adding the following two properties? `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled: true` and `spark.shuffle.service.enabled: true`

Comment: if i add that, I have no cores and no nodes allocated to my sparklyr job :-(

Comment: when i run a command, such as `copy_to`, i get multiple executors allocated on one node, but it then fails with java error `ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated`

Comment: Mmmmm, I don't know about the second error, but try adding also the property: `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors: xx` setting x to the maximum number of cores of your cluster.

Comment: also, when I try to run rsparkling (an implementation of h2o ML algos for RStudio and Spark), I get java error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported argument: (spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled,true)`

Comment: adding `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors:` raises the same java error as before

Comment: It looks like what's happening is 5 executors are being created ON THE SAME NODE. As each executor is set to use 5 cores (usually across different nodes), the total of 25 cores is more than the node has available. So the issue is still not connecting to all available nodes.

Comment: So maybe reducing the number of cores of each executor?

Comment: But the problem remains that all the executors are running on just ONE node. They should be spread over all 6 nodes - and i can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it! It was so simple and obvious I cannot believe I missed it.

The config (`spark-defaults.conf`) file had the settings:

```
spark.executor.cores: 5
spark.cores.max: 12
```

Which of course means it could not start more than 2 (5-core) executors, since the max number of cores the entire app was allowed was 12.